# Does sprint(buf, "%s", buf+10) where strlen(buf+10)>10 count as overlapping?

Tags: c, printf, overlapping

I know I should use memmove if there's overlapping but I can't imagine how sprintf (or memcpy for that matter) would be coded such that it would run into a problem.

Comment: what you write in your question isn't 100% the same what you ask in your title. Because your title is a yes/no question, and your main text seems to be "what implementation would run into a problem?". By the way, I think you can answer the question from your title yourself.

Comment: Overlapping is only an issue when you copy data, so I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Lundin but this call does copy the data from `buf+10` to `buf`.

Comment: I assume it is rather obvious for you that source and destination buffer are overlapping. It might not be a problem in this case but you should just take it as mentioned in the spec: The buffers mustn't overlap. Don't do it.

Comment: Yes it is counted as overlapping. I wouldn't try to do that and rely on it always working.

Comment: @Lundin It would be copying the string stored at buf+10 to buf. If stlen(buf+10) was 20 then it would be copying the bytes from buf+10 to buf+30 (including 0 terminator) to the bytes from buf to buf+20.

Comment: Functions `sprintf` or `memcpy` can be implemented in any way. It is not required to use a loop that starts copying at the beginning. It could also start at the end or copy several parts in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source and target are clearly overlapping. So, yes, this counts.

Comment: While I knew deep down that was the case I felt I had to check as I had to replace one command with 6.

Comment: not a great question, honestly. When you have facts, you don't need reassurance.

Comment: @NoComprende: Note that the behavior is also undefined if `strlen(buf + 10) == 10`

Answer (score 3):

The C Standard is clear, so you should not make any assumptions regarding how `memcpy` could possibly be implemented.  Imagine an architecture where memory can be read a written out of order more efficiently than sequentially. Implementors of `memcpy` could take advantage of the non-overlapping constraint to issue CPU instructions that move multiple words at a time in indeterminate order, thus potentially overwriting source bytes before they are read.